# How to change the connection name in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

I noticed that in the context menu of any connection in Azure Data Studio, there is no rename option. Also, you cannot rename the connection in the Dashboard that opens when you click "Manage" in the mentioned above context menu.
Is there any way to rename a connection created in Azure Data Studio?

Answer (score 5):

Dark Templar's answer works. But you can do it inside of Azure Data Studio by adding New Connection. That opens a sidebar on the right where you can select the connection and change the any of the fields down in Connection Details. Seems like you have to press Connect to save it.

Comment: Correct, but only in the case when you know/remember the connection password.

Answer (score 4):

Figured out the solution. I'm on Ubuntu, and the file, where the information about connections is stored, is found in:
`~/.config/azuredatastudio/User~/settings.json`

Just edit the entries located in the "datasource.connections".

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 it is under the following path:

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\azuredatastudio\settings.json
```

Comment: Note for Win11 this file is now in: `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\azuredatastudio\User\settings.json`